# Needing Help Tweaking The Ability to Customize Message Body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been sitting on this for two weeks and feel really stumped. I'm pretty much an extreme noob who is teaching myself coding so I can create an interactive game with Twine (Sugarcube). Everything in this code is perfect and I've customized it since to my liking BUT I have one glaring issue. Whenever you click on an email, it expands to the same one message body. It doesn't change, no matter which message preview you click.

My request is for anyone that can help me or point me in the direction on how to tweak the "EmailFull" div class (if that's what needs to be tweaked) so that it changes every time you click a different message. I will be forever grateful because I feel like no matter if I create a new div class, rearrange the order, or create a new JS function, it doesn't pan out right.

Here's the full code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/Lance-Jernigan/pen/yJbXOK

HTML:

```
<div class="EmailsWrapper">
        <div class="EmailFull">
            <p>My name is Mark Cohan, and I'm the founder and CEO of Appalo. Appalo is one of the best mobile developer companies in Singapore.</p>
            <p>We have an app out right now.  You can check it out in the appstore.  However, I'm looking to take this app to the next level.</p>
            <p>I really would be excited to work together.  Please do let me know</p>
        </div>
            <div class="EmailTitle">
                <p class="EmailTime">11:12 AM</p>
                <h1>Sergey Zolkin</h1>
                <h2>New Project Inquiry</h2>
                <p class="EmailPreview">Hi Matt! Are you available for...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="Email">
            <div class="EmailTitle">
                <p class="EmailTime">8:13 AM</p>
                <h1>Slack</h1>
                <h2>Notiications from the team..</h2>
                <p class="EmailPreview">Hi Matt, You have a new message...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="EmailTitle">
                <p class="EmailTime">7:24 AM</p>
                <h1>Clark from Invision</h1>
                <h2>Weekly digest: How to design...</h2>
                <p class="EmailPreview">Plus why product thinking is the...</p>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .EmailsWrapper {
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #313a5a 0%,#424a6b 100%);
        }

            .EmailFull {
                position: absolute;
                top: 115px;
                background: #f2f2f2;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0px 25px;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
                max-height: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition: all .3s;
            }

                .EmailFull.active {
                    max-height: 453px;
                    overflow: scroll;
                }

                .EmailFull p {
                    line-height: 1.6em;
                }
            
             .Email {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
                padding: 5px;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 90%;
                max-height: 100px;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 3px auto;
                transition: all .3s;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;
                opacity: 1;
            }

                .Email.active {
                    margin-top: -76px;
                    padding: 10px 0px;
                    background: #21294a;
                    color: #fff;
                    z-index: 15;
                    max-width: 100%;
                    cursor: initial;
                    border-radius: 0px;
                }

                .Email.deactive {
                    max-height: 0px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    margin: 0px auto;
                    opacity: 0;
                }
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".Email").on("click", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active")
        $(".Email").not(".active").addClass("deactive")
        $(".hamburger").addClass("active");
        $(".EmailFull").addClass("active");
        $(".headerLabel h1").text("MESSAGE");
    })
    $(".hamburgerWrapper").on("click", function() {
        $(".Email.active").removeClass("active")
        $(".Email.deactive").removeClass("deactive")
        $(".hamburger").removeClass("active");
        $(".EmailFull").removeClass("active");
        $(".headerLabel h1").text("INBOX");
    })
})
```

Comment: Pay attention to the structure of html. You only have one body with a message - `EmailFull` class.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov i guess my thing is where would I put the other variations of the ```EmailFull``` class? I've placed EmailClass2 & 3 under the first one and you cannot the other message bodies. I've tried to add the message body under each ```EmailPreview``` and it doesn't show up either. That's where I'm most stuck because I feel like I'm on the right track to creating a new class but then am fumbling as to where it should be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the content of .EmailFull properly. I  slightly modified your javascript code to include this

```
$(".EmailFull").html($('<div />').html($(".EmailPreview", this).text()));
```

```js
// Inspired by https://dribbble.com/shots/2810563-Messages-UI-UX-Animation

$(function() {
    $(".Email").on("click", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active")
        $(".Email").not(".active").addClass("deactive")
        $(".hamburger").addClass("active");
        $(".EmailFull").addClass("active");
        $(".EmailFull").html($('<div />').html($(".EmailPreview", this).text()));
        $(".headerLabel h1").text("MESSAGE");
    })
    $(".hamburgerWrapper").on("click", function() {
        $(".Email.active").removeClass("active")
        $(".Email.deactive").removeClass("deactive")
        $(".hamburger").removeClass("active");
        $(".EmailFull").removeClass("active");
        $(".headerLabel h1").text("INBOX");
    })
})
```

```css
body {
    background: #732bde;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

    body * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 320px;
        height: 568px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 8);
    }

        .statusBar {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #21294a;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            z-index: 10;
        }

            .signal {
                margin: 5px 5px;
                padding: 0px;
                display: flex;
                width: 50px;
            }

                .signal > span {
                    display: inline-block;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    width: 5px;
                    height: 5px;
                    border: solid 1px #fff;
                    margin: 0px 1px;
                }

                    .signal > span.active {
                        background: #fff;
                        z-index: 3;
                    }

            .clock p {
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-size: 10px;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            .battery {
                margin: 3px 5px;
                width: 50px;
            }

                .battery span {
                    display: block;
                    height: 7px;
                    width: 17px;
                    border-radius: 1px;
                    background: #fff;
                    position: relative;
                    float: right;
                }
                    
                    .battery span:after {
                        content: " ";
                        display: inline-block;
                        width: 3px;
                        height: 4px;
                        background: #fff;
                        border-radius: 4px;
                        position: absolute;
                        right: -2px;
                        top: 1px;
                    }

        .header {
            padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #21294a;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: flex-end;
            z-index: 10;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #424a63;
        }

            .header:after {
                content: " ";
                display: block;
                height: 4px;
                width: 85%;
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #5a6ab8 0%,#4bafcd 100%);
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -4px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            }

            .hamburgerWrapper {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 50px;
            }

                    .hamburger {
                        width: 13px;
                    }

                        .hamburger.active {
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }

                        .hamburger span {
                            display: block;
                            margin: 2px auto;
                            height: 2px;
                            width: 100%;
                            background: #467797;
                            border-radius: 9px;
                            opacity: 1;
                            transform: rotate(0deg);
                            transition: .25s ease-in-out;
                        }

                                .hamburger.active span:nth-child(1) {
                                    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, -2px);
                                    width: 75%;
                                }

                                .hamburger.active span:nth-child(3) {
                                    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-3px, 2px);
                                    width: 75%;
                                }

            .headerLabel h1 {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 100;
                line-height: 1em;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            .headerMenu {
                width: 50px;
                text-align: right;
            }

                .headerMenu h2 {
                    color: #467797;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-weight: 600;
                    line-height: 1em;
                    padding: 0px;
                    margin: 0px;
                }

        .EmailsWrapper {
            height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #313a5a 0%,#424a6b 100%);
        }

            .EmailFull {
                position: absolute;
                top: 115px;
                background: #f2f2f2;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0px 25px;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
                max-height: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition: all .3s;
            }

                .EmailFull.active {
                    max-height: 453px;
                    overflow: scroll;
                }

                .EmailFull p {
                    line-height: 1.6em;
                }

            .EmailSearch {
                width: 90%;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 65px 0px 20px 0px;
            }

                .EmailSearch input {
                    width: 100%;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
                    outline: none;
                    background: transparent;
                    border: none;
                    padding: 15px 0px;
                    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
                }

                    .EmailSearch input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
                        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
                        font-weight: 100;
                    }

            .Email {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
                padding: 5px;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 90%;
                max-height: 100px;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 3px auto;
                transition: all .3s;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;
                opacity: 1;
            }

                .Email.light {
                    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
                }

                .Email.active {
                    margin-top: -76px;
                    padding: 10px 0px;
                    background: #21294a;
                    color: #fff;
                    z-index: 15;
                    max-width: 100%;
                    cursor: initial;
                    border-radius: 0px;
                }

                .Email.deactive {
                    max-height: 0px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    margin: 0px auto;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                    .Email .ImgWrapper {
                        width: 20%;
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;
                    }

                        .Email .img {
                            width: 40px;
                            height: 40px;
                            background: #fff;
                            border-radius: 100%;
                            position: relative;
                        }

                            .Email .img.notif:before {
                                content: " ";
                                display: block;
                                width: 12px;
                                height: 12px;
                                background: #5bc3e4;
                                border-radius: 100%;
                                border: 2px solid #868b9d;
                                position: absolute;
                                top: -2px;
                                left: -2px;
                                opacity: 1;
                                transition: all .3s;
                            }

                                .Email.active .img.notif:before {
                                    opacity: 0;
                                }

                    .EmailTitle {
                        width: 80%;
                        position: relative;
                        color: #fff;
                        display: flex;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
                        align-items: center;
                    }

                        .EmailTitle .EmailTime {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
                            right: 0px;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            font-weight: 100;
                            margin: 0px;
                            padding: 5px;
                        }

                        .EmailTitle h1 {
                            margin: 0px;
                            padding: 0px;
                            font-size: 15px;
                            line-height: 1em;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            width: 100%;
                        }

                        .EmailTitle h2 {
                            margin: 0px;
                            padding: 3px 0px;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            line-height: 1em;
                            font-weight: 300;
                        }

                        .EmailTitle p.EmailPreview {
                            margin: 5px 0px;
                            max-height: 25px;
                            padding: 0px;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            font-weight: 100;
                            opacity: .8;
                            overflow: hidden;
                            transition: all .3s;
                        }
                        
                            .Email.active .EmailTitle p.EmailPreview {
                                max-height: 0px;
                            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="statusBar">
        <div class="signal">
            <span class="active"></span>
            <span class="active"></span>
            <span class="active"></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clock">
            <p>10:15 AM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="battery">
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerLabel">
            <h1>INBOX</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="headerMenu">
            <h2>EDIT</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="EmailsWrapper">
        <div class="EmailFull">
            <p>My name is Mark Cohan, and I'm the founder and CEO of Appalo. Appalo is one of the best mobile developer companies in Singapore.</p>
            <p>We have an app out right now.  You can check it out in the appstore.  However, I'm looking to take this app to the next level.</p>
            <p>I really would be excited to work together.  Please do let me know</p>
        </div>
        <div class="EmailSearch">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Messages" />
        </div>
        <div class="Email light">
            <div class="ImgWrapper">
                <div class="img notif">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="EmailTitle">
                <p class="EmailTime">11:12 AM</p>
                <h1>Sergey Zolkin</h1>
                <h2>New Project Inquiry</h2>
                <p class="EmailPreview">Hi Matt! Are you available for...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Email">
            <div class="ImgWrapper">
                <div class="img">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="EmailTitle">
                <p class="EmailTime">8:13 AM</p>
                <h1>Slack</h1>
                <h2>Notiications from the team..</h2>
                <p class="EmailPreview">Hi Matt, You have a new message...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Email light">
            <div class="ImgWrapper">
                <div class="img notif">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="EmailTitle">
                <p class="EmailTime">7:24 AM</p>
                <h1>Clark from Invision</h1>
                <h2>Weekly digest: How to design...</h2>
                <p class="EmailPreview">Plus why product thinking is the...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the point in the right direction! One question, now when you click the messages, the body just prints the ```EmailTime```, ```h1```, and ```h2``` of message you clicked. I've been messing around with the ```$(".EmailFull").html($('<div />').html($(this).text()));``` to figure out how to customize the text of ```EmailFull``` separately but having a hard time. Would I have to make another div class for this?

Comment: You already have the class "EmailPreview". I have modified the code to use it for the  email body.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I played around with what you gave me and was actually able to teach myself a little more so this is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know, where your content data (email body text) is comming from and in which element(s) it will be stored, you can basically change the html of your **EmailFull** class every time an email is clicked.

```
$(".EmailFull").html('<p>Some other mail text here.<p>');
```